# How to create Time converter using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

hello im mohammed from sri lanka and new to programing so i am litle bit confused these days

So we have a server in srilanka 
and we have  clients are access to the website from several countries and make reservations
then the server saves the time acording to srilankan time zone so i wont store actual time 
i need hep to resolve thease problems Helpme!and serve me!

EG:

client make order at `3.10am` from USA
     it saves `3.10am` and make Oder *srilankan time* `3.10 am` 
 so i want to atomatically conver to clint country time

how can i code that using `C#` `visual studio 2010`

thanks

Comment: The following question provides some useful information on how to handle timezones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side convert the time to GMT time using [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and store it in your database. Then read it converting as local time zone.

E.g. in your code behind do something on the following lines. Code from MSDN.

```
System.DateTime univDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

to convert it back

```
System.DateTime localDateTime;
try {
    localDateTime = System.DateTime.Parse(strDateTime);
}
catch (System.FormatException) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Invalid format.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: this steps helps me  and can you explain it more i m really new

Comment: @Moahmmed it's better that in the server db you save datetime as universal time (utc or gmt). on the client side whenever you get the time you should convert it to universal time using DateTime.ToUniversalTime and store it in local db. Whenever you want to convert it to local time in any time zone you can do this by using TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(datetime)